# I am not getting classification output by predict_generator()

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset, image-classification

I am trying to classify pre-downloaded images from my dataset to "Rock" , "Paper" , "Scissor" classifications but I am getting outputs as numbers.

I have already divided the dataset to Train folder where 3 folders with the names of the categories exist.

Is it because I am not using a convolutional neural network?

I don't understand what to do here .

***Code:***

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
import numpy as np


train_directory = 'D:\D_data\Rock_Paper_Scissors\Train'
training_datgagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
training_generator = training_datgagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_directory,
    target_size = (28,28),
    class_mode = 'categorical', classes = ["Rock", "Paper" , "Scissor"])

validation_directory = 'D:\D_data\Rock_Paper_Scissors\Train'
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale= 1./255)
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_directory,
    target_size = (28,28),
    class_mode = 'categorical',
    classes = ["Rock", "Paper" , "Scissor"]
    )


model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape = (28,28,3)))
model.add(Dense(128,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',metrics = ['accuracy'],)
filenames = validation_generator.filenames
nb_samples = len(filenames)
desired_batch_size = 1

model.fit_generator(training_generator,epochs=20,validation_data = validation_generator)
predict = model.predict_generator(validation_generator, steps = np.ceil(nb_samples/desired_batch_size))

print(predict)
```

***Output:***

```
[[2.2792105e-01 7.7206087e-01 1.8017196e-05]
 [2.8221733e-03 9.9715865e-01 1.9176909e-05]
 [5.1788869e-04 9.9948126e-01 8.8551565e-07]
 ...
 [9.9283433e-01 7.1645100e-03 1.1474091e-06]
 [9.9999678e-01 3.2666808e-06 4.5816462e-09]
 [9.9640071e-01 3.5960779e-03 3.1497514e-06]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

m.predict_generator returns a numpy array. you can take the maximum probability of a class by numypy argmax function or use predict_classes. This link might help-

[How to predict class label from class probability given by predict_generator for testdata?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/32194/how-to-predict-class-label-from-class-probability-given-by-predict-generator-for?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you it worked!